# Axios on ReactJs not sending BLOB on POST request

Tags: reactjs, blob, axios

I try to send **`blob`** to **`nodeJs`** server

But request is empty object.

Why axios not sending blob?

```
/**
 * Returns PDF document.
 *
 */
getPDF = (blob) =>
{
    return axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://172.18.0.2:8001/export/pdf',
        timeout: 3000,
        data: {
            blob: blob,
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return {
            status: response.status,
            data: response.data
        }
    })
}
```

this variable blob is **`png`** image exported to **`blob`**

There is screen shot of the network

[image]

And there is screen shoot of consol.log-ed blob variable before sending axios request

[image]

Comment: `headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }`

Comment: Also relevant: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1569, https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/415

Comment: How did you figure this out?